# RPC using JSON but not JSONRPC in Substrate

Tags: substrate

I want to write an RPC service which can uses JSON as RPC payload but it does not follow JSONRPC standards. Also I want to execute pallet's extrinsic function based on JSON DATA received on RPC How to achieve these goals?
I tried to read Moonbeam's code but that seems too complicated to achieve above goals.

Comment: It might help if you explained why you didn't want to follow the JSONRPC standards? I.e. what you're finding hard / not supported.

Comment: Not every blockchain follows JSONRPC standard. If you take tezos as example it uses its own JSON format.